# Unable to set object notation based on parent child using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here i am newbie to angular and javascript here what i am trying to achieve is i have  a couple of data

```
 data = ['middlename.firstname.lastname','firstname.lastname'];
```

and now i am looping in the .html  using the below approach

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data">

   <p *ngIf="x.indexOf('.')!==1">
       {{x.split('.')[1]}}
   </p>

</div>
```

Here my issue 
  in the **data** if u see there is  "'middlename.firstname.lastname" where **middle name**  is parent and remaining all are children so based on that in the front end i am displaying the postion 1 which is after the parent  upto this is working. But if u see  2nd data there is "firstname.lastname" here the parent is not there so it is displaying according to the position "Lastname" here i want to  display the **firstname** even though it has no parent.

below is my stackblitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmdaxg

```
Present output :
          firstname
          lastname
expected output :
          firstname
          lastname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the correct thing to do would be to create the correct dataStructure in your component and display in the component.

```
    dataToDisplay = this.data.reduce((acc, elem) => {
        if (elem.indexOf('.') !== 1) {    // because you have done this check in your HTML
          let nameSplit = elem.split('.');
          if (nameSplit.length === 2) {
            acc.push(nameSplit[0]);
          }
          else if (nameSplit.length === 3) {
            acc.push(nameSplit[1])
          }
         return acc;
       }
    }, []);
```

And then loop over `dataToDisplay` in your `HTML` to display the output

```
<div *ngFor='let x of dataToDisplay'>
  <p>{{x}}</p>
</div>
```

Or, If you specifically want to do it in your HTML itself, then you can have something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data">
   <p *ngIf="x.indexOf('.')!==1">
       <ng-container *ngIf="x.split('.').length === 2">
          {{x.split('.')[0]}}
       </ng-container>
       <ng-container *ngIf="x.split('.').length === 3">
          {{x.split('.')[1]}}
       </ng-container>
   </p>
</div>
```

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkqxxa